# Models of extensions of ZFC, within $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Is it the case that every consistent recurively axiomatized extension of $\sf ZFC$ has a model in a level of the constructible universe below $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$? If not, then what is the least consistency strength of such an extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what sort of model you're looking for - $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is either unspeakably more or vastly less than is necessary.

---

If you just want any old model, then the answer is yes - massively so. The model construction process in the proof of the completeness theorem is fully definable, and so if $T$ is a consistent theory which is a definable subset of $L_{\omega+\alpha}$ then $T$ has a model in $L_{\omega+\alpha+1}$. In particular, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has a model in $L_{\omega+1}$. *(In fact, we can do much better than this via the low basis theorem, but that only works for countable theories and isn't necessary for the question as posed.)*

**Note that the strength of the theory is totally irrelevant; we have a single process (the Henkin process) which builds a model of a given theory if such a model exists in the first place, so the only thing that matters is the complexity of the theory itself.**

On the other hand, if you're looking for *well-founded* models, then $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ isn't nearly enough: it doesn't even have a well-founded model of Kripke-Platek set theory with infinity ($\mathsf{KP\omega}$). Indeed, it's not even enough to build an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{KP\omega}$. However, it is worth noting that we have an analogue of the low basis theorem for $\omega$-models, the *Gandy basis theorem* which implies in particular that every computably axiomatizable extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which has an $\omega$-model has an $\omega$-model which is "low for hyperjump." That still doesn't get us down to $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, but it's quite a useful observation.

*(Roughly, the reason $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ doesn't contain an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{KP\omega}$ is the following. If $M$ is an $\omega$-model of $\mathsf{KP\omega}$ then the well-founded part of $M$ has height $\ge\omega_1^{CK}$, and in fact $M$ is an end extension of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$. Now if $M\in L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ we would have $M\in L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}$. But we also have $L_{\alpha+1}\in M$ in an appropriate sense, and so we get a contradiction after a quick diagonalization.)*