# $L_{\omega_{1}^{CK}}$ and models of $\mathsf{KP \omega}$ set theory

Tags: set-theory

On the one hand, this [paper](http://kamerynjw.net/research/pubs/least-models/kwilliams-least-models.pdf) states that $L_{\omega_{1}^{CK}}$ is the minimum transitive model of $\mathsf{KP \omega}$ (KP + Infinity) set theory. On the other hand, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3730767) states that "$L_{\omega_{1}^{CK}}$...doesn't even have a well-founded model of...$\mathsf{KP \omega}$"

Is there a contradiction between these two statements, or are they describing two subtly different things (different in some way that I don't quite grasp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no contradiction.

Being a transitive model and having as an element a well-founded model are two very different things.

This is similar to how a model of $\sf ZF+\operatorname{Con}(ZF)$ will have a model of $\sf ZF$, but it might not have a model of $\sf ZF+\operatorname{Con}(ZF)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction between these two statements, but they are describing different things. To clarify the situation, let's break down the notations and definitions involved.

$L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$: This notation refers to the $\omega_1^{c K}$-th level of the constructible universe L. The constructible universe L is a class model of ZFC constructed using the Gödel operations. The levels of L are cumulative and transitive, which means each level includes all the elements of previous levels and is closed under the membership relation.

$\mathrm{KP} \omega$: This is an abbreviation for the Kripke-Platek set theory with the Axiom of Infinity. The Kripke-Platek set theory (KP) is a weaker version of ZFC, which omits the Axiom of Choice, the Axiom of Regularity, and the full Axiom of Replacement. Instead, KP includes a weaker version of Replacement called the Axiom of Σ-Collection.

Now, let's consider the two statements:

The paper states that $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ is the minimum transitive model of $\mathrm{KP} \omega$ set theory. This means that the level $\omega_1^{c K}$ of the constructible universe L is the smallest one that satisfies the axioms of the Kripke-Platek set theory with the Axiom of Infinity.

The answer states that $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ doesn't even have a wellfounded model of KP $\omega$. This statement suggests that there is no wellfounded submodel of $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ that satisfies the axioms of KP $\omega$. Note that this is different from saying that $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ itself is not a model of KP $\omega$.

In summary, the two statements are not contradictory. The first statement claims that $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ is the minimum transitive model of $\mathrm{KP} \omega$ set theory, while the second statement claims that there is no wellfounded submodel of $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ that satisfies the axioms of KP $\omega$. These are two different claims about the properties of $L_{\omega_1^{c K}}$ and its submodels.